# Ableton Issue while trying to control click

Tags: autohotkey

Even though I have read the docs and watched tutorials I am a complete beginner so I apologize If its a silly question. I have tried for quite a while to do this with no results.

I want to have NUMPAD0 key to press the global recording button in Ableton Live but I do not want to do it through mouse coordinates (1. Because the windows might be minimized when I need to record and 2. Because I want to implement this in the future in order to be able to press the recording button also on individual tracks as I create them, which might range from 1 to 80 new tracks for example)

The thing is that the Windows class dynamically changes and the Control ID is not shown in winspy.

This is what I have been doing:

```
GroupAdd, Live, ahk_class 
Afx:0000000140000000:0:0000000000000000:0000000000900015:00000000007A04C3
GroupAdd, Live, ahk_class 
Afx:0000000140000000:0:0000000000000000:0000000000900015:0000000000200651
GroupAdd, Live, ahk_class 
Afx:0000000140000000:0:0000000000000000:0000000000900015:0000000000290651
GroupAdd, Live, ahk_class 
Afx:0000000140000000:0:0000000000000000:0000000000900015:00000000001E05F1

curMode := 1
return


Numpad0::
 SetControlDelay -1
 controlclick, ahk_group Live0,,,,,NA
 return
```

So, my issues are these: 1. In the GroupAdd command I have put the window classes that I have seen yet I believe there might be more classes, that appear everytime I open a new Ableton window. 2. In the Control Click command, I havent put the control ID because I couldnt find it.

Any advice on how to finish this code or change it to a different it in order to press that Record button in Ableton, without using coordinates?

EDIT: 
This is the code Im trying now, following suggestions but I havent got any results yet:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow

#IfWinActive, .*als
Numpad0::F9
#IfWinActive
return
```

And this is the 2 version of that, which is not working either

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow

#IfWinActive, Afx:0000000140000000
Numpad0::F9
#IfWinActive
return
```

Comment: Doesn't the program have a keyboard shortcut (look in the manual) or a menu item for the global recording, besides this button? Instead of the group, you can use
`SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx` and only a part of the window's class in the ControlClick command.

Comment: Yes, it does exit but I want to be in the numpad because I would like to set, not only the global but also individual tracks for recording from the numpad too (for which there are no default hotkeys in ableton).  This is what im doing now to at least get the global recording going, but still no results. (I swapped the F9 key which is the default recording hotkey in ableton for numpad0).  I have edited my question to post the code Im doing now!

Comment: `#IfWinActive, ahk_class Afx:0000000140000000` is the right syntax in this case. Try also the Send or the ControlSend command.

Comment: The thing is that weirdly, the control ID or class NN is also dynamically changing so I dont know how to use controlsend with a control ID that is continually changing. Also, the Ahk_class and the Class NN( which Is what I read should be put under the control parameter in control send) have almost the same numbers, so it is a bit difficult to also identify the wintitle from the Class NN because of this.  I will be trying a few other things and if nothing works, I will resort to find a way to change the key shortcuts inside the program the way I want it, Hopefully its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I've never used `GroupAdd`, if there's a finite number of Class permutations, it seems to me you could `RegExMatch` against those and then form your group inside that. The `GroupAdd` spec seems to make all parameters optional beyond the GroupName, so perhaps you could skip the Class declaration after confirming you've got the right window.

**Example:**

```
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinGetClass, Class, A
if (RegExMatch(Title, "Ableton Live.*") AND (RegExMatch(Class, "(AbletonClass1|AbletonClass2|AbletonClass3)")))
{
    ; Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I managed to make it work. I did it by using the exe name instead and it worked. I did change it a bit but still, it gave me a very good start. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @A.R.Leon You're very welcome. Glad it helped! When you get a moment, please accept this as the answer or submit your own so it's taken out of circulation for the Unanswered questions. :)

Comment: Hey David! I just pressed the checkmark and it turned green. I read that was the way to accept an answer, hopefully I did it properly!

Comment: @A.R.Leon You betcha! Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!